# Zend_Mime_Part could not be converted to string magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, email, plugin, send-mail

I am implemented functionality to change store info in email templates, for that I have created plugin

```
public function aroundSendMessage(\Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface $subject, \Closure $proceed){

        $message = $subject->getMessage();
        $body= str_replace("post@example.com","hello@hello.com", $message->getBody());
        $message->setBody($body);
        $message->setReplyTo("heelo@heelo.hff");
        try {
            $proceed();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
        }
}
```

But am getting below error

> Recoverable Error: Object of class Zend_Mime_Part could not be
>   converted to string

Comment: $message->getBody() does not always return a string

Comment: How can I replace my string in  $message->getBody()

Comment: try $message->getBody(true)

Comment: you issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

$message->getBody() does not always return a string

try `$message->getBodyText(true)`

This will force htmlOutput

Comment: no still same error

Comment: @Daniel_12 sorry. see updated answer

Comment: Now I dnt get the error but my email body is empty :(

Comment: issue fixed? or not